# Как вывести изображение, которое находится за пределами корня сайта?

Tags: php, файлы, img, upload

PHP

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']; // Временный путь
    $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']; // Фактическое имя файла сохраняется в этой переменной
    $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size']; // Указывает размер загруженного файла в байтах.
    $fileType = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type']; // Содержит mime тип загруженного файла
    $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));

    $newFileName = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension; // новое имя файла
    $allowedfileExtensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'); // расширения которые доступны

    $uploadFileDir = "D:/OpenServer/domains/";
    $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $newFileName;

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)) {
      if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)) {
        $message = 'File is successfully uploaded.';
        echo '<img src="'.$uploadFileDir.''.$newFileName.'" />'; // ЗДЕСЬ ПЫТАЮСЬ ВЫВЕСТИ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ
      } else {
        $message = 'There was some error moving the file to upload directory. Please make sure the upload directory is writable by web server.';
      }
    }
  }
```

Я сохраняю изображения за пределы корня сайта, что бы нельзя было иметь прямой доступ к ним, и пытаюсь вывести на странице, но у меня не получается. Подскажите может так нельзя делать? Я так же пробовал указать такой путь `../`

Comment: Никакого отдельного "прямого доступа" в природе не существует. Все обращения браузера к серверу "прямые".

Поэтому вопрос "как мне закрыть доступ к изображению и вывести его" является бессмысленным.

Comment: Странно, но к примеру возьмем файлы .zip и будем хранить их за пределами корня сайта. И с помощью header() я укажу абсолютный путь сервера за пределами корня и этот файл успешно скачается пользователю не показывая ему ссылку, да и к тому же запретит прямой доступ. Сейчас вопрос с выводом изображения. Я думаю Вы не правы.

Comment: Во-первых, "с помощью header() я укажу абсолютный путь сервера за пределами корня и этот файл успешно скачается" - это такая же бессмыслица. сначала попробуй сделать, как написал, а потом расскажи что у тебя получилось

Comment: Во-вторых, ты должен определиться, хочешь ты показываь картинку, или нет. Если хочешь, то нет смысла её прятать.

Comment: @Ипатьев Вот с файлом
 $file = '/var/www/123.zip';

  if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }

Comment: ну и где здесь "с помощью header() я укажу абсолютный путь сервера"? Я не вижу в header никакого "абсолютный путь"

Comment: @Ипатьев но задача в том что картинку нужно показать администратору, но никак не другим пользователям. Я думаю использовать как вариант .htaccess и запретить прямой доступ, но мне кажется это все равно не безопасно, если кто то догадается и будет выводить с помощью тега img. Просто, если даже моя идея нереализуема, то это печально. Я подумал было бы круто сделать так, как с файлами примера .zip

Comment: @Ипатьев Значит я видимо не так выразился с помощью header отправляю заголовки и вытаскиваю файл из предела корня сайта, где храню путь в переменной $file, но это сути не меняет вопроса, если можно с файлом, то возможно с изображением получится?

Comment: я тебе уже писал, что **нет никакого прямого доступа**. Через .htaccess ты можешь просто закрыть доступ. ЛЮБОЙ. Это на редкость дурацкая идея - думать что браузер запрашивает какртинки каким-то "кривым способом".

Comment: ну вот "с помощью header отправляю заголовки и вытаскиваю файл из предела корня сайта" - можно.

Comment: Но тогда так с самого начала и надо было делать. Потому что картинка, РНР файл и зип архив НИЧЕМ не отличаются для браузера. Кроме НТТР заголовка.

Comment: для вашей задачи небось будет достаточно просто скрывать `<img>` в случае, если пользователь не авторизован/не администратор. Файл вы в вашем примере скачиваете не с помощью header а читая его через пхп - `readfile`. В целом вы можете и картинку отдать через пхп, для авторизованного пользователя, но в целом это требует больших ресурсов и массовое применение не желательно.